# How to check equality between pandas dataframe multiindex subset?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I've got two dataframes `df1` and `df2`, and each one have a multiindex. the first multiindex's columns are `['A','B','C','D']`, and the second `['A','B']`.

I want to get the dataframe `df` containing the rows of `df1`, where `df1[['A','B']] == df2[['A','B']]`. This syntax works when `['A','B']` are some columns of my df, but not when `['A','B']` are in index. (I would rather avoid `df.reset_index()`)

Here is the minimal example :

```
L = ([["foo","blih",23,1],
     ["foo","blah",2,13],
     ["bar","blih",1,23],
     ["bar","blah",2,31]])

example = pd.DataFrame(L,columns = ["A","B","value1","value2"])
L2 = ([["blih",23,1],
      ["blih",1,23]])
example2 = pd.DataFrame(L2,columns = ["B","value1","value2"])
example = example.set_index(["A","B"])
example2 = example2.set_index(["B"])
```

Here is the dataframe `example` :

```
          value1  value2
A   B                
bar blih       1      23
    blah       2      31
foo blih      23       1
    blah       2      13
```

and `example2` :

```
      value1  value2
B                
blih      23       1
blih       1      23
```

Expected output : **The rows of `example` where `example['B'] == example2['B']`**

```
          value1  value2
A   B                
bar blih       1      23
foo blih      23       1
```

Comment: Can you add some data samples?

Comment: I added a minimal example

Comment: OK, what is expected output?

Comment: Of course there are no rows where that condition holds but you already know it.

Comment: Oh sorry, small mistake, I'm looking for the rows where `example['B'] == example2['B']` ! Fixed it. Also precised what I wanted as output

Comment: Ok everything should now be correct and clear

Comment: @Goyo I corrected my mistakes and tried to be as clear as possible, might you remove your downvote ? Thanks

Comment: But that is not example['B'] == example2['B']. You cannot even evaluate that. Maybe have a look at [advanced indexing with hierarchical index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#advanced-indexing-with-hierarchical-index) in pandas.

Comment: Why are you so against `reset_index`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to match on multiple column values, some of which are in the index and some of which are not. `DataFrame.merge` is really what you want.

```
example.reset_index().merge(example2).set_index(['A', 'B'])
```

output:

```
          value1  value2
A   B                   
bar blih       1      23
foo blih      23       1
```

The only reason you need `reset_index` on the left `DataFrame` is because the merge will not preserve the multi-index for index columns that are not keys. That is,

```
example.merge(example2, on=['B', 'value1', 'value2'])
```

outputs:

```
      value1  value2
B                   
blih      23       1
blih       1      23
```